# Does merging segments in Google Map Maker ever work?

Tags: google-maps

When editing line segments in Google Map Maker, the number of crossings one needs to touch for a change is pretty relevant. From my experience, every move of a crossing needs to be reviewed, so the number of crossings needed to be moved is the number of round trips one needs for a change.

So, one way to improve this would be to remove crossings which anyway only connect two segments first. However, I've never been able to do this. I always get an error message saying that the segments to be merged have different attributes. I tried to find the differences, but without success.

But let's start with a general question: Did anyone ever successfully remove a crossing in Google Map Maker?

---

This is the full error message (in German):

> Segmente mit ungleichen Attributen können nicht zusammengeführt und
>   die entsprechenden Kreuzungen können nicht gelöscht werden. Die
>   Segmente, die an dieser Kreuzung enden, weisen Attribute auf, die
>   nicht zueinander passen. Bitte korrigieren Sie dies und versuchen Sie
>   dann erneut, die Kreuzung zu löschen.

and it translates to:

> Segments with unequal attributes can not be merged and the
>   corresponding intersections can not be deleted. The segments ending at
>   this intersection have attributes that do not match. Please correct
>   this and then try to clear the intersection again.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Google Map Maker has Closed: https://support.google.com/mapmaker/answer/7195127

Answer (score 1):

I managed once to remove a crossing connecting two railway segments. All other times I get this error message too. I even checked all properties of the two segments t be the same as far as shown. I guess this is an internal bug in the google map maker.

Removing crossings that connect two segments that have (nearly) the same properties should IMHO even get done automatically.